# using Django Session

Tags: python, django, session

I want to show user login info using session. 
Please Help me. Thank you.
My code is here.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    bbs_query = models.Blog.objects.all()
    try:
        if(request.session['logined_user']):
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'blogs': bbs_query})
    except KeyError:
        return redirect('login')
```

index_header.html

```
 <b class="hidden-xs">{% request.session['logined_user'] %}</b>
```

I want to render from view.py to index.html. But index.html includes index_header.html.
So, I want to show session info in index_header.html.

Comment: you can directly access from request.user

Comment: There is no problem with getting the data in an included template. But you have two major errors with your template syntax, plus there shouldn't be anything named "logined_user" in your session; the user is available from `request.user` rather than from the session dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display user data, use `request.user`:

```
 <b class="hidden-xs">{% request.user %}</b>
```

Also your template syntax is incorrect, check [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#syntax) of the doc.

`request.session['logined_user']` should be written `request.session.logined_user` but there is no reason to have a `logined_user` in your template in first place.

Comment: hello, how do you do? thank for your help.
could you explain where is incorrect my template?